# Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot in Moodle after PHP upgrade

Tags: moodle

I am new to moodle and I have voluntarily assisted one of the schools to set up their moodle page as Covid19 has recently hit us. The Moodle was working fine until I upgraded the PHP version from 7.2 to a higher version. This resulted in an error similar to this and I have no idea where to begin. I checked the config file and seems like everything is looking perfect but as I novice, I might miss important things that need to be adjusted. I am running moodle on a Cpanel on A2hosting to host our moodle.

Can someone pinpoint what would be caused by this and how to address it?

Thanks in advance and looking forward to all the help I can get.

Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiti

Config.php

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'mariadb';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';
$CFG->dbname    = 'xxxxx';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'xxxxx';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'xxxxx';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdlne_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbsocket' => '',
  'dbcollation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'https://www.moodle.chevalier.edu.ki';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/home/chevki/moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

require_once(_DIR_ . '/lib/setup.php');

// There is no php closing tag in this file,
// it is intentional because it prevents trailing whitespace problems!
```

Comment: It would be helpful to share the full error message, as "Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot" is not much to go on. You could also read the instructions at https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Debugging#In_config.php as to how to enable debugging via the config.php file, as that may give more details about what is going wrong.

Comment: You are right Davosmith, I thought the full message was included but I missed it. I have edited my post.

Comment: Problem solve, seems like I need to clear the cache but I didn't think of that when I first see the problem.